# I need to populate a name field on a Case record based on the lookup selection of a user ID, both contained in a custom object

Tags: custom-object, workflow, case

I have a custom object that contains information on all of the associates in my company.  In the case record, I have a lookup field that allows the agent to select an associate's User ID from that custom object.  I want to auto populate the user's name based on the selection of their ID in the lookup field.  I have attempted to use workflow for this process but am having no luck.  I'm a newbie and would appreciate any assistance you could provide.

Answer (score 1):

If you're creating the case from the related custom object you can use url hacking to pass in default values for fields.

There are several tutorials out there (just search for "salesforce url hacking").  I've found [this one](http://raydehler.com/cloud/clod/salesforce-url-hacking-to-prepopulate-fields-on-a-standard-page-layout.html) to be useful.

**Disclaimer** this technique is not supported by Salesforce since it depends on undocumented functionality and while it's unlikely they'll ever break things (people have been doing this for a long time), it is a possibility.

Of course, if you're not creating it from the related object you have to do other things.

## Use a formula field

If users never need to override the value from the related record, just skip having them enter it.  Instead create a formula field to pull the value down onto the related record

## Use Workflow

If users can change it you're not going to be able pre-populate the value, but you can overwrite whatever they enter with the correct value.

Create a worklfow that fires on new cases with a lookup to your related object populated.  The do a field update that uses a formula for the field update, e.g. `Lookup_To_Related_Object__r.Value_I_Want__c`.

## Triggers

If you're scenario is more complex or isn't possible with workflow or formula fields you'll need a trigger.  At that point the sky's the limit.  You just need a developer to write it for you.

Comment: Thanks Ralph.  This is something I've never heard of.  I'll give it a look.  However, as a clarification it is not my intention to create the case from the custom object.  This is an ancillary function to capture requests from clients that come to the support center via another associate (i.e.sales) as opposed to being initiated by the client themselves.

Comment: adding some additional options